# Can´t Login with Twitter

Tags: swift, firebase, twitter

Im trying to Login with Twitter with Firebase in my app i set up everyting but i get this error in console:

> Error Domain=TWTRNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed:
>   forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error
>   : Callback URL not approved for this client application.
>   Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application
>   settings (code (null)), TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=403,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)

I have set the Callback URL in my twitter settings but i get still that error

That´s my code:

```
let twitterLoginBtn = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint("Couldn´t LogIn with Twitter: ", error)
            return
        }

        if let session = session {
            let credentials = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: session.authToken, secret: session.authTokenSecret)
            self.firebaseLogin(credentials)
            print("signed in as \(session.userName)")
        } else {
            print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    twitterLoginBtn.center.x = twitterLoginView.center.x
    twitterLoginView.addSubview(twitterLoginBtn)
```

heres twitter settings:

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue let me know if you find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

To use the SignIn with Twitter service, you have to add the Firebase (like `my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`) callback URL you're using to a whitelist in your [Twitter App Dashboard](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps)!

More information here in the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/apps/guides/callback-urls.html) ;)